# add custom method in jquery validator

Tags: jquery, validation

I am learning jquery validator plugin. I have create custom validator method and apply it to first name input. But it is not working and after adding that other validation also not working correctly. I just want to know what i have done wrong.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44funjz2/)

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(){
    alert("form submited")
}
})  


$('#theform').validate({
    rules:{
    fname:{
    required:true,
    name:true
    },
    lname:"required",
    username:{
    required:true,
    minlength:2
    }           
},
messages:{
    fname:"first name is required",
    lname:"last name is required",
    username:{
    required:"this field is required",
    minlength:"atleast two charactor is required"
    }

    }


})

jQuery.validator.addMethod("name", function(a, b) {
    return a.indexOf('john')!=-1;
    }, "Please enter name john");
```

Comment: Validation working for me

Comment: I have add custom method in first name but it is working for username

Comment: This plugin looks tedious to me. Try this one instead: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation I used it personally and loved it!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/44funjz2/5/

**HTML**

```
<form id="theform">

...
        <label>name</label>
        <input type="namevalidation" id="fname" name="fname" required />
...

</form>
```

**JQ**

```
//to add validator method for name
//1. change input type e.g. "namevalidation"
//2. in addMethod for name take mentioned value: "namevalidation"
//3. addMethod methods must go before attaching validate plugin
$.validator.addMethod("namevalidation", function (a, b) {
    return a.indexOf('john') != -1;

}, "Please enter name john");


$('#theform').validate({
    //pay attention to the creation of rules and use {} for each rule
    rules: {
        fname: {
            required: true,
        },
        lname: {
            required: true,
        },
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2

        }
    },
    //use {} for each message
    messages: {
        fname: {
            required: "first name is required"
        },
        lname: {
            required: "last name is required"
        },
        username: {
            required: "this field is required",
            minlength: "atleast two charactor is required"
        }

    }

});
```